# tsan complaints with notify_all_at_thread_exit

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-sanitizer

When I run code that calls notify_all_at_thread_exit() from a detached thread, tsan complains about a data race between pthread_cond_broadcast and pthread_cond_destroy.  Am I doing something wrong?  Or is this a false positive from tsan?

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main(int, char**){
    mutex m;
    condition_variable cv;

    bool done = false;
    thread([&](){
               this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(100));
               unique_lock<mutex> lk(m);
               done = true;
               notify_all_at_thread_exit(cv, std::move(lk));
           }).detach();

    unique_lock<mutex> lk(m);
    cv.wait(lk, [&]{ return done; });
    std::cout << "Done\n";
    return 0;
}
```

```
drdws0134$ garden with -m gcc/9.2.0-02c7/bin -- g++ -std=c++17 -fsanitize=thread bug1.cpp -O0 -ggdb -pthread && ./a.out
Done
==================
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=27370)
  Write of size 8 at 0x7ffd05131540 by main thread:
    #0 pthread_cond_destroy /tmp/garden-install.88e036900cee/+tmp+/untar/gcc-9.2.0/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors.cc:1171 (libtsan.so.0+0x30c66)
    #1 main /u/nyc/salmonj/junk/thread_notify_bug/bug1.cpp:12 (a.out+0x402627)

  Previous read of size 8 at 0x7ffd05131540 by thread T1:
    #0 pthread_cond_broadcast /tmp/garden-install.88e036900cee/+tmp+/untar/gcc-9.2.0/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors.cc:1164 (libtsan.so.0+0x30b63)
    #1 __gthread_cond_broadcast /tmp/garden-install.88e036900cee/+tmp+/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/gthr-default.h:853 (libstdc++.so.6+0xd1ad8)
    #2 std::condition_variable::notify_all() /tmp/garden-install.88e036900cee/+tmp+/untar/gcc-9.2.0/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/condition_variable.cc:73 (libstdc++.so.6+0xd1ad8)

  Location is stack of main thread.

  Location is global '<null>' at 0x000000000000 ([stack]+0x00000001e540)

  Thread T1 (tid=27372, finished) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create /tmp/garden-install.88e036900cee/+tmp+/untar/gcc-9.2.0/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors.cc:964 (libtsan.so.0+0x3057b)
    #1 __gthread_create /tmp/garden-install.88e036900cee/+tmp+/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/gthr-default.h:663 (libstdc++.so.6+0xd6fe4)
    #2 std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) /tmp/garden-install.88e036900cee/+tmp+/untar/gcc-9.2.0/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/thread.cc:135 (libstdc++.so.6+0xd6fe4)
    #3 main /u/nyc/salmonj/junk/thread_notify_bug/bug1.cpp:15 (a.out+0x4025a4)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race /u/nyc/salmonj/junk/thread_notify_bug/bug1.cpp:12 in main
==================
ThreadSanitizer: reported 1 warnings
drdws0134$
```

FWIW, I get a very similar error from TSAN with clang8 and libc++:

```
drdws0134$ garden with -m clang/8.0.0-06c7/bin -- clang++ -Wl,-rpath,/gdn/centos7/0001/x3/prefixes/clang/8.0.0-06c7__4bf264b1013a/lib -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++17 -fsanitize=thread bug1.cpp -O0 -ggdb -pthread && ./a.out
Done
==================
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=27396)
  Write of size 8 at 0x7ffea2b603e8 by main thread:
    #0 pthread_cond_destroy /tmp/garden-install.d86e7e77c946/clang-8.0.0-06c7/compiler-rt/lib/tsan/rtl/tsan_interceptors.cc:1216 (a.out+0x46b7b1)
    #1 main /u/nyc/salmonj/junk/thread_notify_bug/bug1.cpp:26 (a.out+0x4c69b1)

  Previous read of size 8 at 0x7ffea2b603e8 by thread T1:
    #0 pthread_cond_broadcast /tmp/garden-install.d86e7e77c946/clang-8.0.0-06c7/compiler-rt/lib/tsan/rtl/tsan_interceptors.cc:1209 (a.out+0x46b6bd)
    #1 std::__1::__thread_struct_imp::~__thread_struct_imp() /tmp/garden-install.d86e7e77c946/clang-8.0.0-06c7/libcxx/src/thread.cpp:173 (libc++.so.1+0x8b17d)

  Location is stack of main thread.

  Location is global '<null>' at 0x000000000000 ([stack]+0x00000001e3e8)

  Thread T1 (tid=27398, finished) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create /tmp/garden-install.d86e7e77c946/clang-8.0.0-06c7/compiler-rt/lib/tsan/rtl/tsan_interceptors.cc:980 (a.out+0x452aa6)
    #1 std::__1::__libcpp_thread_create(unsigned long*, void* (*)(void*), void*) /gdn/centos7/0001/x3/prefixes/clang/8.0.0-06c7__4bf264b1013a/bin/../include/c++/v1/__threading_support:328 (a.out+0x4c7eec)
    #2 thread<(lambda at bug1.cpp:15:12), void> /gdn/centos7/0001/x3/prefixes/clang/8.0.0-06c7__4bf264b1013a/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:368 (a.out+0x4c6b65)
    #3 main /u/nyc/salmonj/junk/thread_notify_bug/bug1.cpp:15 (a.out+0x4c6922)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race /u/nyc/salmonj/junk/thread_notify_bug/bug1.cpp:26 in main
==================
ThreadSanitizer: reported 1 warnings
drdws0134$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I believe there is a possible race condition.

`std::notify_all_at_thread_exit` is specified to do the equivalent of `lk.unlock(); cv.notify_all()` as the thread exits.  If your main thread were to experience a spurious wakeup immediately after `m` is unlocked, then it would see that `done` is `true` and could reach the end of `main` and destroy `cv` before `cv.notify_all()` gets called.

Comment: There is a recent LWG issue: https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3343

Comment: Timely!  The LWG issue is only a week old.  Is there anything I can do other than wait for a standard library that addresses the LWG issue?  E.g., call std::yield() before the cv goes out of scope to give the detached thread another chance to call cv.notify_all()?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to keep a handle to the thread and `join()` it before `cv` goes out of scope.  If you don't need the semantics that `notify_all_at_thread_exit` provides wrt thread locals you could also just call `cv.notify_all(); lk.unlock()` yourself instead.

Comment: I'm leaning toward allocating the cv on the heap with `new std::condition_variable` and never delete-ing it.  The idea being that leaking a few bytes is less bad than risking calling cv.notify_all on a destroy-ed object.